# pandas: find the first shipped product from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
product_id        shipping_date                  price        quantity
  AX-11           2014-11-02T01:00:04+00:00       200            1
  BA-45           2012-05-23T01:00:02+00:00       4000           5
  XF-55           2011-01-12T01:00:07+00:00       400            10
  ..................................................................
```

I'm trying to get the product that was shipped first, the answer should be `XF-55` since it was shipped in `2011-01-12T01:00:07+00:00`.

I tried the following code and that doesn't seem to work:

```
df2 = df.groupby('product_id')['shipping_date'].transform("min")
```

This just gives me a new DataFrame with `product_id` and they aren't sorted at all. How do I just get the `product_id` of the first shipped product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`idxmin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) to get the row index of the earliest shipping date. You can then use `loc` to fetch the value at that row from the product ID column:

```
>>> df.loc[df['shipping_date'].idxmin(), 'product_id']
'XF-55'
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-11-20T21:17:52+00:00` error when I use that code

Comment: I'm not sure how that error arises from applying this code to your example DataFrame. Is the 'shipping_date' column of dtype datetime64? If not do `df['shipping_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['shipping_date'])` first.

Answer (score -1):

I would use NumPy's `argsort` for this:

```
sortidx = np.argsort(df['shipping_date'])
```

This gives you an array of indexes which sort the data.  So the first index in the returned array is the index of the lowest `shipping_date`.  Then:

```
df['product_id'][sortidx[0]]
```

Should give you the result you want.